# How does "samesite: strict" work when only the hostname is present?

Tags: cookies

Suppose you're accessing `http://hello`, relying for example on the default connection suffix to find the host `hello` on the local network, or discovering `hello` with mDNS.

The browser requests `GET /, Host: hello`. How is the following returned HTTP header supposed to work?

```
Set-Cookie: a=b; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
```

Should the cookie be sent back when refreshing the page?

What about the case of pure IP addresses as hostnames?

Comment: I'm asking because I see a flacky behaviour with Firefox 80-84 in this situation, it looks like sometimes no cookie is send back, sometime it is. The cookie by the way is a session cookie set by a response of a previous XmlHttpRequest, that triggers `document.location.reload(true)` in the browser. It reloads, but cookies for that host are cleared before sending the request. I'm trying to isolate the true reason, but the "bug" is difficult to reproduce reliably.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr `document.location.reload(true)` after a cross-site navigation still includes the `referer` and still counts as cross-site as far as Firefox is concerned for `SameSite=strict` cookies.*

With respect to `SameSite=strict`, each of those URLs should behave as a separate site and cookies should be sent as per usual.

My suspicion here is that what you might be encountering is that the `document.location.reload(true)` is not resulting in a same-site request as far as cookies are concerned. I tried this in Firefox by setting up a simple test page that sends the cookie you specified above.

This is the page (with some of the boilerplate removed) and I'm serving on `8080`.

```html
<html>
<button type="button">Reload</button>
<a href="http://hello:8080"><code>http://hello:8080/</code></a>
<script>
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => { location.reload(true) });
</script>
```

In my `/etc/hosts` file, I have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost hello
```

Open up DevTools in Firefox so you can look at the Network requests

If I visit `http://localhost:8080` then I will see the `a=b` cookie set for `localhost`.

If I follow the link to `http://hello:8080`, I will see that no `a=b` cookie is sent as the first cookie is just for `localhost`. However, `hello` does set the `a=b` cookie. Also note, the header `Referer: http://localhost:8080/` showing us that we have a cross-site request.

If I click the button to initiate a reload or press the reload button in the browser, then the `Referer` header **is still set** and even though the cookie is set, it is not set.

If I follow the link `http://hello:8080` link from this page, then I now have `Referer: http://hello:8080/` and the `a=b` cookie is sent.

If instead that link goes to `redirect.html` which looks like this:

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://hello:8080/'"/>
<title>Redirecting</title>
```

Then I will see:

- `localhost:8080` → `hello:8080/test.html` - no cookies, `localhost` referer
- `hello:8080/test.html` → `hello:8080` - cookie sent, no referer

Trying the same thing in Chrome and it does seem to treat the `reload()` as a same-site request and sends the cookie.

Comment: Note I'm not trying to pass cookies between `localhost:8080` and `hello:8080`. The fact that the two hosts entry point to the same IP is irrelevant, as it should be.

Comment: I'm trying to isolate a case where a refresh (of the same page) is apparently (mis?)interpreted by the browser as cross-site, or at least this seems to be the case given the side effect of it (no strict cookies sent). Original questions is: what's the "site" of a URL that contains just an hostname without any dot?

Comment: When I tried with `hello`, `a.hello`, and `a.a.hello` locally it appeared as if each acted like a separate site. However, sticking with the more convential `hello.local`, `a.hello.local`, and `a.a.hello.local` and then `hello.local` was the site and the `SameSite=Strict` cookie was sent on requests between them. Ensure you remember to set `Domain=hello.local` on the cookie though, otherwise it will be excluded from requests to subdomains.

Comment: What do specification say about multiple requests to `http://hello`? Intuitively, they should be same site, but what's the official expected behavior? Also after hitting _Refresh_? Also after re-typing the URL manually and pressing _ENTER_?

Comment: The important bit is the context of the request. A Refresh is a bit like repeating the request with the same context. e.g. if I make a cross-site navigation and refresh the page, it's still a cross-site request. If I type a URL in directly, that's same-site. You can look at the `sec-fetch-site` request header in Chrome DevTools to get an indicator of this. The spec defines same-site / cross-site here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site-00#section-2.1

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think we isolated the problem, also thank to your explanation. I suggest to proceed as follows: answer the direct question with "yes, multiple requests to `http://hello` are all considered same site". I'll give you then two files to replicate the problem, that seems to happen in Firefox only (approx. version 80), I'd like to get your opinion. I'll write to the FF team if you think Firefox behavior is wrong, as I can't replicate such behavior with Chromium-based MS Edge. Files are here: https://github.com/openmediavault/openmediavault/issues/926#issuecomment-762340214